# Calling a method from another Activity (call Fragment)

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock, fragment

I have called method:

```
protected void ask(){

        Fragment newContent = new QuestionsFragment();
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).switchContent(newContent, R.string.questions, MenuFragment.questions_id, BottomActionBarMode.QUESTIONS);
}
```

MainActivity:
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B30eXgoSJlFsczNSdkE5Qnc5eG8/edit?usp=sharing

Error:

> 08-21 17:16:28.574: E/AndroidRuntime(26360): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   08-21 17:16:28.574: E/AndroidRuntime(26360): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.chiv.successteritory.activities.AskLikeQuestionDetailsActivity cannot be cast to com.chiv.successteritory.activities.MainActivity

how to call? thanks in advance

Comment: trouble in this `(MainActivity) getActivity()`

Comment: try `(AskLikeQuestionDetailsActivity) getActivity()`

Comment: @LiaPronina But that class most likely doesn't have that `switchContent` method.

Comment: Where are `ask` and `switchContent` methods located?

Comment: ask() in AskLikeQuestionDetailsActivity, switchContent(.. ) in MainActivity

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Once you start the AskLikeQuestionDetailsActivity, it's not guaranteed that MainActivity is still there (as it's gone to background, the OS can garbage collect it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on `MainActivity` and starts the `AskLikeQuestionDetailsActivity`, it's not guaranteed that `MainActivity` is still there, as the OS can garbage collect any Activities on background.

If you want change a `Fragment` on `MainActivity` after the `ask()` method is called on `AskLikeQuestionDetailsActivity`, I would suggest you to do the following:

On `MainActivity`, instead of calling `startActivity` to start `AskLikeQuestionDetailsActivity`, call `startActivityForResult` and override the `onActivityResult` method to change the `Fragment` depending on the result received.

On `AskLikeQuestionDetailsActivity`'s `ask()`, call `setResult` with `Activity.RESULT_OK` and a configured `Intent` to send some information back to `MainActivity`, then call `finish()` (if you have to exit the `AskLikeQuestionDetailsActivity` `Activity` right away).

Is it clear? Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, It's an option I understand, but do not know how to implement.
The main task is to call the fragment: QuestionsFragment

Comment: But why do you need to call a method from another Fragment from another Activity (that might not even be in memory by the time you need it) directly?

Comment: Can  call not directly. After running the code - [link](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B30eXgoSJlFsZWdqQ2ljS3A2Rnc/edit) I have to open the fragment - [link](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B30eXgoSJlFsSWtFNFFFaDNEZFk/edit)

Answer (score 0):

In ask() AskLikeQuestionDetailsActivity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
        int condition = 1;
        intent.putExtra("condition", condition);
        startActivity(intent);
```

In onCreate() MainActivity.class:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        showQuestions();
    }
```